Java abstract service with abstract mappers
To reduce the amount of code, I thought of creating an abstract service like that (it is just a "sketch"):
public abstract class CrudService<E extends EntityWithId<ID>,ID,R extends JpaRepository<E,ID>>{
    protected R repository;

    public CrudService(R repository){

        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ID create(E entity) {
        return repository.save(entity).getId();
    }

    public List<E> readAll(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    public Optional<E> readById(ID id){
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    public boolean update(E entity){
        if(!repository.existsById(entity.getId())){
            return false;
        }
        repository.save(entity);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean delete(ID id) {
        if(!repository.existsById(id)){
            return false;
        }
        repository.deleteById(id);
        return true;
    }
}

After that I decided to implement DTO pattern, but here is a problem, I don't know how to write an abstract mapper, or if I even should do such a thing. Maybe the idea of abtract service class is bad and I should just split it in specific ones for each entity in my domain?

I don't understand why you do this. You just add one more layer of method calls.

Interfaces with default methods might be something too; more for the repository it seems. Note: you can always refactor a bit later removing repetive code. Then you see how much you gain.

@alalalala it is the case right now, but service layer will handle mapping and validation in the future.
